# TypeScript keyed array of JSON objects missing properties error

Tags: arrays, typescript, angular8

I am working on an Angular project in which I have a service with an array of Query objects. My trouble is the compiler complains with the following error message about missing properties in my array which is not clear to me:

```
  ERROR in src/app/query.service.ts:8:3 - error TS2740: Type '{ '1': Query; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Query[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

  8   query: Query[] = {
  ~~~~~~~~~
```

My code is below.

*query.service.ts:*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Query } from './query/query.module';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class QueryService {
    queries: Query[] = {
        '1' : new Query( {"type":"test","id":"1","data":["test---data",{"misc":["alt-url","alt-redirect","published-date","granted-approved","signed-off"],"default":"true"}]} ),
    };

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.queries);
  }
}
```

*query.model.ts:*

```
export class Query {
    public id: number;
    public type: string;
    public options: string;
    public sections: string;

    constructor(data: any) {
      const json_data = JSON.parse(data);
      this.id = json_data.id;
      this.type = json_data.type;
      this.options = json_data.options;
      this.sections = json_data.sections;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning an object to array type.
Your QueryService queries should have type of Record not Query[]:

```
export class QueryService {
    queries: Record<string, Query> = {
        '1' : new Query( {"type":"test","id":"1","data":["test---data",{"misc":["alt-url","alt-redirect","published-date","granted-approved","signed-off"],"default":"true"}]} ),
    };

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.queries);
  }
}
```

or other way around:

```
queries: Query[] = [
    new Query( {"type":"test","id":"1","data":["test---data",{"misc":["alt-url","alt-redirect","published-date","granted-approved","signed-off"],"default":"true"}]} ),
];
```